# Liquidation price calculation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, economics

Suppose I want to open a long position (that which increases in value as the commodity goes up in value) in some commodity whose price at the time of opening the trade is, say, $p$. The position is opened on margin, and the margin is 3 times of the collateral. That is, if I have $p$ dollars in my margin account I can open a position of size $3p$, and the liquidation price will be $p$. Suppose also that the collateral for the commodity I'm trading in the long position is also denominated in the said commodity, which means that as the commodity goes down, the liquidation price (when the position has to be closed) goes up.

Now, I want to obtain the graph of the liquidation price change.

Let $y$ be the liquidation price and $x$ be the price of the commodity. Suppose I have 1 unit of the commodity and I open a long position for 1 unit. I think that in this case I come up with the following differential equation:

$$3 \frac{dy}{dx}=-x, y(p) = \frac{p}{3},$$

which doesn't give me the correct graph.

Can someone please help me with this? I'm missing some important point here and thus the DE I'm coming up with is not correct.

Comment: I imagine you'll get a better response if you translate your problem into a purely mathematical problem rather than one that requires knowledge of financial terminology. (and maybe even better understand the problem yourself!)

Comment: The liquidation price is derived from the Black-Scholes equation for option prices.  This is looking to see if you understand it.  The liquidation price is related to the price of an option by the no free lunch theorem.

Comment: I think it is possible in this case not to use the Black-Scholes equation. This would be an overcomplication.

Answer (score 1):

The pde that describes the problem is

$$ \frac{dy}{dt} = -\frac{1}{3}\frac{dx}{dt}$$

Where y is the liquidation price and x is the commodity price.  As x goes down the liquidation price goes up.

$$Y(0) = \frac{X(0)}{3} = \frac{p}{3}$$